# External HDD is getting Unmounted for no Obvious Reason

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd

So, I have a HDD in a docking station that is connected via USB to my computer. I am running a python script stored on that drive that might be doing a lot of I/O (I didn't create the script, I am just using it). At the very least, the error messages tell me that it checks the current working directory a lot for some reason. The bottom line is that, when I run this script, the HDD unexpectedly gets unmounted at some point while the script is running. During my first attempt, it ran almost 48 hours before this happened. In subsequent attempts, it lasted 10 minutes and 40 minutes.

I checked both ends of the USB connection. While they have some wiggle room, it isn't enough to cause a physical disconnect (I tried). It also doesn't seem to be something with the HDD as simply turning off, then on, the docking station and/or unplugging and replugging in the USB cable seems to get the computer to remount the drive with no issues.

One thing I could try is running it using my internal drive. However, I am a bit nervous about what might happen if that ends up getting unmounted while the script (and all my other programs) is running.

Any ideas?

---

Edit:

Per waltinator's suggestion below, I ran the following after determining which device it was.

```
sudo zgrep '/dev/sdc' /var/log/*
```

This is what I got:

```
/var/log/udev:DEVNAME=/dev/sdc
/var/log/udev:DEVNAME=/dev/sdc1
/var/log/udev:DEVNAME=/dev/sdc2
/var/log/udev:DEVNAME=/dev/sdc
/var/log/udev:DEVNAME=/dev/sdc1
/var/log/udev:DEVNAME=/dev/sdc2
```

I am not sure if there is anything useful in there. It is important to note that the HDD appeared to be properly mounted at the time I did this. I am guessing there would be something else if I ran then after it got unmounted?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the script?

Comment: What size HDD? Does the docking station have its own AC power supply? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: You could probably gain some information with `zgrep '/dev/sd' /var/log/* | less`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was traveling this past week.

@PSA Unfortunately, I cannot post the script. The collaborator I got it from still wants to do some clean-up before releasing it publicly.

Comment: @heynnema The HDD is 3TB and the docking station has its own AC power.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try.